# Fastest disk based solution to cache trillions of unique md5 hashes

Tags: database, performance, caching, indexing, nosql

Is there a very low latency disk based caching solution that I can use to store only unique values (NOT key+value)?

My script needs to keep track of which files it has processed so it doesn't redo any work. I need to check the cache to search for the md5 hash of the file, if it doesn't exist, I process the file and add the hash to the cache.

Is there a faster disk based caching solution than using a key-value based solution?

Comment: First, let's decide whether the space is practical.  "Trillions" of 16-byte quantities = a very huge disk.  Meanwhile, "fast" implies SSD.  Is there hardware available with 100TB of SSD?

Answer (score 2):

Do the math.  1 trillion MD5s, without any tricks, would take 16TB of disk space.  This is, I assume, far more than your RAM size.

Since each MD5 lookup is essentially a 'random' probe into the disk, there will necessarily be about 1 disk hit per check.

If, say, an SSD read is 1ms, that is 1e9 seconds to insert (or check) a trillion hashes.  That's 30 years.

There are a lot flaws in my math, but I think this says that it is not practical *today* to store and check a trillion of anything random.

If you want to crank it down to a billion MD5s, now we are getting in the range of RAM sizes.  But you probably want to have the data persisted?  So you really need some database-like tool that will do the persisting for you, while making the checks purely in RAM (CPU-speed).

In any case, I would consider writing code that breaks the MD5 into 2 or 3 chunks, then use the chunks like a directory structure.  At the bottom level, you have a variable-length bunch of values for the last chunk.  Each is perhaps 8 bytes long.  That would need a linear or binary search into a bunch of numbers that are half the size of an MD5.  The savings here helps compensate for the various overheads in the rest of the structure, plus the need for writing blocks to disk.  Hence, I would still expect needing *about* 16GB of RAM to house a billion MD5s.

Given that approach, virtually any database engine is already geared up to do most of the work reasonably efficiently.  The lowest level would be some type of BLOB containing multiple 8-byte chunks.

Another trick to use...  Let's look at just the first 5 bytes of an MD5.  There are a trillion different values in 5 bytes.  If you have only a billion entries in your dataset, then checking the 5 bytes has a 99.9% chance of correctly saying "the md5 is not in the dataset" versus less than 0.01% chance of saying "the md5 *might* be in the dataset".  In the former case, you get a quick answer with only 5GB for a billion items.  In the latter case, you may have to go to disk and be slower.  Still the *average* time is better.  This helps with the speed of checking.  (But does not address the speed of loading.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb).

It's a key-value store but is very compact due to the [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure.

Less space usage => less I/O => better performance.

Not sure about "*trillions*" (a trillion MD5 hashes would be 16,000 TB), but Bitcoin core as well as Ethereum implementations all use LevelDB.

Comment: Do you know what terminology is used to describe just storing values (rather than key-value store)? I guess ill just have to store the md5 hashes as the key and null as the value for now using LevelDB.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there is no need for an "Ordered Key-Value Store". That is you can rely on plain Key-Value stores (direct dbm successors):

Good candidates are:

- [tokyo cabinet](https://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) it has a hash-based format, that might be faster in your case.
- [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)

In the case where the datatset fit into memory, you might want to try LMDB.

I do not recomment LevelDB because it is slow.

Comment: Thank you. You mentioned LevelDB is slow, how much slower than the options you listed?

Comment: Apparantly, not much, the best thing is to benchmark yourself. Here is some benchmarks: http://www.lmdb.tech/bench/ondisk/